# error while using ESP-IDF MQTT TCP example (0x8006 & 0x8004)

Tags: mqtt, esp32, mosquitto, esp-idf

I am trying to use example from esp-idf protocal/mqtt/tcp

I changed the user name and password using `idf.py menuconfig`

then after erasing flash using `esptool.py --port /dev/ttyUSB0 erase_flash`

After build I uploaded the code to ESP32 using

```
idf.py build
idf.py -p /dev/ttyUSB0 flash
```

And when I monitor it

`idf.py -p /dev/ttyUSB0 monitor`

It Showed the following error

```
    I (4609) esp_netif_handlers: example_netif_sta ip: 192.168.69.134, mask: 255.255.255.0, gw: 192.168.69.50
    I (4609) example_connect: Got IPv4 event: Interface "example_netif_sta" address: 192.168.69.134
    I (5609) example_connect: Got IPv6 event: Interface "example_netif_sta" address: fe80:0000:0000:0000:7ae3:6dff:fe18:eeb8, type: ESP_IP6_ADDR_IS_LINK_LOCAL
    I (5609) example_common: Connected to example_netif_sta
    I (5619) example_common: - IPv4 address: 192.168.69.134,
    I (5619) example_common: - IPv6 address: fe80:0000:0000:0000:7ae3:6dff:fe18:eeb8, type: ESP_IP6_ADDR_IS_LINK_LOCAL
    I (5639) MQTT_EXAMPLE: Other event id:7
    E (14809) esp-tls: [sock=54] delayed connect error: Connection reset by peer
    E (14809) transport_base: Failed to open a new connection: 32772
    E (14819) mqtt_client: Error transport connect
    I (14819) MQTT_EXAMPLE: MQTT_EVENT_ERROR
    E (14829) MQTT_EXAMPLE: Last error reported from esp-tls: 0x8004
    E (14829) MQTT_EXAMPLE: Last error captured as transport's socket errno: 0x68
    I (14839) MQTT_EXAMPLE: Last errno string (Connection reset by peer)
    I (14849) MQTT_EXAMPLE: MQTT_EVENT_DISCONNECTED
    E (83319) esp-tls: [sock=54] select() timeout
    E (83319) transport_base: Failed to open a new connection: 32774
    E (83319) mqtt_client: Error transport connect
    I (83319) MQTT_EXAMPLE: MQTT_EVENT_ERROR
    E (83329) MQTT_EXAMPLE: Last error reported from esp-tls: 0x8006
```

But when I using wifi/getting_started example from esp-idf doing the same as above it works perfectly fine

I am a newbie so I am finding it hard to understand the error

```
ESP_ERR_ESP_TLS_FAILED_CONNECT_TO_HOST (0x8004): Failed to connect to host
ESP_ERR_ESP_TLS_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT (0x8006): new connection in esp_tls_low_level_conn connection timeouted
```

---

As per hardillb's suggestion I used ESP32 as access point :-

after using one ESP32 as access point `wifi/getting_started/softAP`
when I am trying to use the same example on second ESP32 :
`protocal/mqtt/tcp`
I am facing error

```
E (562605) esp-tls: couldn't get hostname for :mqtt.eclipseprojects.io: getaddrinfo() returns 202, addrinfo=0x0
E (562605) transport_base: Failed to open a new connection: 32769
E (562605) mqtt_client: Error transport connect
I (562615) MQTT_EXAMPLE: MQTT_EVENT_ERROR
E (562615) MQTT_EXAMPLE: Last error reported from esp-tls: 0x8001
I (562625) MQTT_EXAMPLE: Last errno string (Success)
I (562625) MQTT_EXAMPLE: MQTT_EVENT_DISCONNECTED
I (572635) MQTT_EXAMPLE: Other event id:7
```

Comment: Did you also update the broker host IP/name? And can you access the broker from a different machine? Mosquitto defaults to only accepting connections from localhost these days

Comment: this is my mosquitto.conf file are you refering to this
`persistence true`

`persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/`

`include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d`

`listener 1883 `

`allow_anonymous true`

Comment: well thats what I was trying to do using 2 esp to access it without localhost,  i.e for wifi I am using mobile hotspot

Comment: Mobile hotspots usually have something called "Client isolation" which prevents different wifi clients connecting to each other.

Comment: So can you suggest how can I use 8 ESP(all connected on an Exo skeleton) for wireless data acquisition? or something else which I can use for the same

Comment: Try with a proper WiFi Access Point, not a moblie hotspot

Comment: I used the SoftAP example on ESP32 and tried the same MQTT TCP example on other ESP 32 but it showed the following error that I edited in question at last